# How to combine if and cycle in Excel or Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, xlsx, xls, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to calculate a sum of all string lenghts in column `B` which are in the same row with an `int` or `float` number in column `A`. How can I do this in cycle for any combination of values in column `A`? I'm completely lost with if and cycle notation of Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try SUMPRODUCT function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER($A$2:$A$13)*LEN($B$2:$B$13))
```

[image]

Comment: @F.Vosnim Yes it is possible to add multiple ranges  - if the range is continuous then simply specify it in the existing LEN function, eg ```LEN(B2:C13)``` . If there are several separate ranges, each range must use its own LEN function and combine them with addition, eg ```(LEN (B2:B13) + LEN (C2:C13) + LEN (E2:E13))```. Note: ranges must be the same size